# Use view with Entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, view

I’m developing an application where I’m using Entity Framework. I have a table A and an autogen entity from this table class A

```
Public Class A

    ID As Integer
    Sum As Integer
    TotalSum As Integer
    LastPayment As Integer
    NewPayment As Integer
      .
      .
      .
End Class
```

In addition to my table I have a view that calculates and returns all the rows from table A where totalSum and LastPayment meets some conditions (table has 50 rows, view returns 35 rows).
Can I use this view together with my entity class A? When I use my entity class A I  can say

```
unitOfWork.ARepository.Filter(Function(p) p.ID = Me._id, , )
```

but this will get the rows from the table without the calculations/filtering done by the view, let say it returns 50 row. I want to say

```
unitOfWork.ARepository.Filter(Function(p) p.ID = Me._id, , )
```

but I want to get the filtered rows from the view instead, this will return 35 rows instead of the 50. But I do not want the view to be an entity in my model, because I then will have two classes A (from table) and B (from view) that looks exactly the same. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can write a code corresponding view with entity framework in VB or C#. it's better than use 2 model that are equal.